# How to query session stored in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I've configured my web application to use database instead of file to store sessions. So far so good.

I could store a pair of key value easily like this:

```
$request->session()->put('current_page', $request->route()->uri());
$request->session()->save();
```

Now I want to make an SQL query to retrieve all sessions which have the value **users** paired with current_page key and where user_id **IS NOT NULL**.

```
$query = DB::table('sessions')->whereNotNull('user_id')->whereJsonContains('payload', ['currrent_page' => 'users'])->get();
```

The previous query returns no rows!!

Comment: pretty sure the playload is base64 encoded serialized data not JSON

Comment: I guess the correct syntax would be `->whereJsonContains('current_page->users', 'payload')`

Comment: @lagbox Yes. The payload column stores the values as base64. Should I do some configuration to make it work?

Comment: @Donkarnash column:payload, key:current_page, value:users

Comment: you would have to spin through every session and decode and unserialize the payload and check them for what you wanted

Comment: You can define an accessor to decode and unserialize the column value. Then probably you can use `->whereJsonContains('payload->current_page', 'users')`

Comment: Could you refer me to some link that explains how such a thing can be achieved?

Comment: its a loop, `base64_decode`, `unserialize` and how ever you want to find what you need in the array of session data

Comment: I haven't worked with session in database or querying session records from database. Yeah and my bad, an accessor won't come into play when records are being queried from database. accessor only comes into play once the records are retrieved from database.

Comment: How about creating a column in the sessions table name current_page? Wouldn't that be better for performance than looping the retrieved result set?

Comment: how would you be setting this new field?

Comment: I used a middleware whenever a user requests the page the current_page column gets updated. Then I can use a normal query like this: pastie.org/p/7FTmgJIgJbv44tpUJ977tL here is the middleware: http://pastie.org/p/64heiG1ahepxsctoZf5l0o It works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is base64 encoded serialized data you can loop through all the sessions and decode and unserialize their payloads to find the ones you want:

```
$sessions = DB::table('sessions')->whereNotNull('user_id')->cursor();

$filtered = $sessions->filter(function ($session) {
    return collect(unserialize(base64_decode($session->payload)))
        ->get('current_page') === 'users';
});

foreach ($filtered as $session) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Even though this is the correct answer to my question. It's not the best solution to my problem. I recommend that storing data related to session in separate columns inside the  sessions table.